# Qt - Pull out a QWidget from the QMdiArea

Tags: c++, qt

I want to try something and google wasn't helpful until now. Maybe I am searching for the wrong keywords.
In my Qt application, I have a QMainWindow with a QMdiArea. where I create a lot of QWidgets in. Everything in there works fine and no problems.
Now, to use for example 2 monitors, I want to pull with the mouse one of the QWidgets out from the QMdiArea and make it a stand-alone QWidget and later on I want to drag it in. 
Is this possible in Qt5? If yes, how?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: would you share more example what you want?

Comment: Yes it is possible in Qt5 and Qt4. The [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html) class provides a widget that can be docked inside a [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) or floated as a top-level window on the desktop.